# thrift hbase client - support filters and coprocessors

Tags: python, hbase, thrift

Sadly, My hbase client language is Python, I am using happybase for now which is based on thrift AFAIK. I know thrift so far is still not supporting filters, coprocessors (correct me if I am wrong here). Can some one point me any Jira items I can track the plan/progress if there is one? The only ones I can find is from "Hbase in Action":

- “Thrift server to match the new Java API”:
  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-1744
- “Make Endpoint Coprocessors Available from Thrift”:
  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-5600

The 1st one doesn't seem covering filters and the 2nd one hasn't been updated for a long while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters are supported through Thrift. Here's a HappyBase example:

```
table = connection.table("mytable")
g = table.scan(filter="SingleColumnValueFilter ('f', 'column1', =, 'substring:text')")
for key, data in g:
    print data
```

Also check out [Thrift book](http://hbase.apache.org/book/thrift.html) for information on various filters and their configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> Family Filter
>
> Description: This filter takes a compare operator and a comparator. It
>   compares each qualifier name with the comparator using the compare
>   operator and if the comparison returns true, it returns all the
>   key-values in that column
>
> Syntax: QualifierFilter (, ‘’)
>
> Example: "QualifierFilter (=, ‘Column1’)"

I think it is a mistake in it