# how can i run RandomRowFilter in happybase

Tags: python, random, filter, happybase

I want to sample rowkey in hbase by happybase(because of memory limit)
So I search and implemet

```
import happybase

"""~ """"
table = connection.table('drivers')
a=list(table.scan(filter="RandomRowFilter (chance=0.1f)" ))
or a=list(table.scan(filter="RandomRowFilter ('chance',=,'0.1')" ))
print a
```

but it always say 
    thrift.Thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing scannerOpenWithScan

is there any example code for RandomRowFilter example in python?

version check is all right because of [[thrift hbase client - support filters and coprocessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070303/thrift-hbase-client-support-filters-and-coprocessors]) I ran this code...

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think happybase that has no filter related to randomfilter.
I mistake that happybase uses HBASE JAVA class related to filter.
But happybase owns their filter.
So I need to make JAVA application to sample hbase row key